Ensuring changed permissions on a external HDD stay intact and don't reset on disconnect/reconnect?
System is a simple Windows 10 Home ver 22H2 Build 19045-5247.
The hard drives in question are Western Digital My Passport's 0837 and 0748.
This is for personal use.
Any permission based changes on a external HDD only work for the time its connected, and disconnecting and reconnecting it restores its permissions back to what it was before.
Say I modify the "Everyone" usergroup to only allow reading files, as soon as I safely remove and reconnect, this usergroup once again has Full Control instead.
Is there any way at all to modify the permissions of an external HDD and have them stay intact between different PC's? They are regular Western Digital external drives, nothing fancy.
Is there a registry edit I can safely do?? Anything at all??
References:

My PASSPORT Portable Hard Drive User Manual


Are the disks using NTFS? Does it happen with other computers?

@Ramhound No no, they are already accessible.
I am trying to change that behavior to specifically remove write/modify access for standard users but not admins. Use case is ensuring my current app blocker can't be easily circumvented by moving files around, that's it.
I had that context in the original post but community bot thought it or something else was too much detail so I toned it down and removed all that.

@grawity NTFS - yes. Other computers, as in trying the same thing in a different system? If yes, I will have the chance to try in an hour or two.
If you mean a network/office setup, no, these are personal systems, apologies for the confusion if I caused any.

@TheWriteQuest Please, add to your post the exact Windows version by using the winver command and, model and specs of the HDD.

@JorgeLuiz Sure, one moment. The issue is resolved but ya never know I guess. EDIT: Done.

The owner had not been properly changed on the entire drive. Fixing this by changing the owner to an admin on the PC I am using ensured that the permissions changes stick to what I want.
Do note if your drive has folders such as $Recycle Bin or $System Volume Information, you might want to keep an Everyone usergroup with full rights for those folders, Recycle Bin will keep throwing an error about being corrupted otherwise, it wasn't in my case, but did confuse me for a hot second lol. If in doubt, CrystalDisk or chkdsk away as needed.
